# Can I build in a pause between executions in cloud functions?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I have a python script that executes every time a file is uploaded in a storage container. If I upload many files at once, only 2 rows show, the oldest file and the most recent (I think). Is there a way to have cloud functions pause for a second in between each execution?

I have tried to change the maximum concurrent requests per instance when editing the function and increased the CPU however, I am still missing rows. I changed it to 10 concurrent instances. I uploaded 7 files and only 5 rows appeared.

code example

```
from google.cloud import storage

from cloudevents.http import CloudEvent
import functions_framework
import pandas as pd
import re, datetime
import gspread
import glob
import gcsfs
from gspread_dataframe import set_with_dataframe
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file('test.json', scopes=scopes)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

gauth = GoogleAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# open the google sheet we are working with.
gs = gc.open_by_url('URL OF SHEET')
# select the Total worksheet.
main_Sheet = gs.worksheet('Total')

# Triggered by a change in a storage bucket
@functions_framework.cloud_event
def find_file(cloud_event: CloudEvent) -> None:
    """Cloud Function triggered by Cloud Storage when a file is changed.

    Gets the names of the newly created object and its bucket then cleans the file and imports a row to a google sheet.
    """

    # Check that the received event is of the expected type, return error if not
    expected_type = "google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized"
    received_type = cloud_event["type"]
    if received_type != expected_type:
        raise ValueError(f"Expected {expected_type} but received {received_type}")

    # Extract the bucket and file names of the uploaded file
    data = cloud_event.data
    bucket = data["bucket"]
    filename = data["name"]
    #print(filename)
    #print(f'gs://{bucket}/{filename}')
    # Process the information in the new file if the name of the file has the string in its title.
    if re.search('STRING',filename):
      #print("working!")
      hello_gcs(bucket, filename)
    else:
      print("no valid file found")




def hello_gcs(bucket: str, filename: str):

   
  
  
  day = re.search('(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\-\d{4}',str(filename))
  date = datetime.datetime.strptime(day.group(), '%d-%b-%Y').date()
  #date
  fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='PROJECT_NAME')
  file = fs.open(f'/bucket_name/{filename}',"r")
  
  read = file.readlines()
      
  ##This is a safe range for the data we are after and should account for any changes in the rows that may happen.
  Main_DF = read[50:100]
  
  ##Splitting the data and cleaning out the = dividers
  Main_DF = [row.strip().replace('=','').split(', ') for row in Main_DF]

  ##Getting rid of whitespace
  Main_DF = [row[0].split() for row in Main_DF]

  ##Convert to data frame
  Main_DF = pd.DataFrame(Main_DF)

  ##
  ##
  ##edited out all of the cleaning and data work here
  ##Mostly using pandas to manipulate the data and clean it to import it into a google sheet.
  ##
  ##

  #Combine everything into one DF
  df_Output = pd.concat([var_1,var_2,var_3,var_4,var_5])
  df_Output = pd.DataFrame(df_Output)

  #Add the column for type
  df_Output['Type'] = ['typeA','typeB','typeC','typeD','typeE']#, ignore_index= True)
  df_Output = df_Output.rename(columns={0: 'Amount'})
  #print(df_output)


  ##Reshaping and creating date field
  df_Output_Main = df_Output.set_index('Type').transpose()
  df_Output_Main['Date'] = str(date)

  #Write data frame to applicable Gsheet
  df_values = df_Output_Main.values.tolist()
  gs.values_append('Total', {'valueInputOption': 'RAW'}, {'values': df_values})
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Instead of asking how to limit Cloud Functions, you should probably instead ask about how to make your code execute correctly, showing that code and enough information that anyone cause to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DougStevenson I added some code to show you the overall process. The code itself is working fine if I upload one file at a time, it is when I import many files at once that I get the issue I explained.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions are designed to scale massively with multiple concurrent invocations.  There is no supported way to limit them in sequence, as that's not a supported use case.  You should instead try to figure out how to make your code work in parallel.  Either that, or choose a different backend product.

Comment: Hello Doug, not sure if you noticed above, but I did include the code to show the overall process.